# A generalization of Jordan curve theorem involving Warsaw circle

Tags: general-topology

When I first looked at Jordan curve theorem my impression was: "Wow, a complicated theorem telling us something obvious!" Let me state the Theorem:

> Let $C \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be a set homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$. Then $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ has two connected components: one of them is bounded, the other one is unbounded.

What about changing hypothesis? What about if $C$ were (homeomorphic to) the Warsaw circle? Intuitively, I think that the answer would be the same: $C$ divides the plane in a space having two connected components, one bounded and the other one unbounded.

But is this true? How can we prove this? Is it a corollary of Jordan's theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to generalize Jordan's theorem. One is more geometric, and leads us to the Schoenflies theorem: "every closed curve in $\mathbb R^2$ bounds a disc". This is to give control on the shape of the two regions.

The other way is to let us relax conditions on the shape involved. This is a bit harder and more algebraic. To do this, we want to use [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality).

The resulting version of the theorem we get is "Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Then if the 1st Cech homology $\check H_1(X) = \mathbb Z$, then the complement has two connected components, one bounded and the other unbounded."

This includes, in particular, the Warsaw circle.

Comment: It might be anachronistic to call this special case Alexander duality. I don't know the history here.